# How to implement more than 2 level navigation in com.android.support:leanback-v17

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-5.0-lollipop, android-tv

In regular android application I can use navigation drawer for navigate between top level views (sections of app)
What should be used in tv apps?
I see only possibility for two level of content organizing Categories -> Movies
But in our app we have several sections (Live channels, On demand Movies, Recorded shows etc) with categories in most of them.
Is it possible using standard android.support.v17.leanback.app.BrowseFragment and android.support.v17.leanback.app.DetailsFragment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short: no. `BrowseFragment` and `DetailsFragment` are meant to be a quick and easy way for developers to bring their content to TVs. They *force* you to that particular structure, which is pretty simple to understand and to navigate.

If you are willing to go all in for a custom experience, you will need to build your version of the `BrowseFragment`, by using a `HeadersFragment` and a `RowsFragment`. This proves to be **quite a headache**, but I managed to do it for my company's application. If you're interested, I will write a post/article on this.

**EDIT**

Here's [the article](https://medium.com/building-for-android-tv/building-for-android-tv-episode-2-e06cadc4f6f5)! It's part of a bigger collection called [Building for Android TV](https://medium.com/building-for-android-tv), if you want to have a look.

Comment: `If you're interested, I will write a post/article on this.`


Yes it would be intresting.

And thanks for HeadersFragment, RowsFragment

Comment: I'll be interested in your article too.

Comment: The article is being written, but unfortunately it's hard to explain exactly how to do it, since there's quite a lot of work to do. In the meantime, the first part of the article is online: https://medium.com/p/2d03f9ba541e/

Comment: FYI - Leanback Updates Introduced After This SO Question Was Written & Answered: https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/screenshots/Showcase-Snapshots.png and the tutorial video to go along with code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFHIfQy8_Wc