# Another Row Layer on BrowseFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tv, leanback

I wonder if its possible to use a BrowseFragment with another Layer/Level of Rows.
something like

```
cat1 - row1 -> item1 -> subrow1
cat2 - row2 -> item1 -> subrow2
```

and so on.
Is there something i can do with a BrowseFragment and the Adapter to get that hierarchy or should i implement it myself?

And how could i implement that myself? i would spawn another Activity with a VerticalRowFragment but thats not exactly the same.

Any hints or tipps are welcome. [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26186129/1367571). I'm trying to finish the second part of the tutorial series, that explains (and shows the code) that does exactly that.

If you want to see an example (and you have a Nexus Player / ADT-1), please check out the [musixmatch application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.musixmatch.android.lyrify.tv). It is build using that exact same technique.

**EDIT**

Here's [the article](https://medium.com/building-for-android-tv/building-for-android-tv-episode-2-e06cadc4f6f5)! It's part of a [bigger collection](https://medium.com/building-for-android-tv), if you want to have a look.

Comment: Thanks dextor, i read your first article, looking forward to the second part!